# How is my laptop ram running in dual channel?

Tags: laptop, memory, dual-channel

I have an ASUS x555l laptop with intel core i5-5200u, geforce 840m and 6gb of ram.
I wanted to upgrade the ram so i did some research and found out that 4gb of ram is soldered to the motherboard and 2gb is in the second slot. as far as i know dual channel only works with ram sticks with the same size so it should be running in single channel but when i checked cpu-z and aida64 both show that the laptop is running in dual channel: [cpu-z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Fo1.png) [aida64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMlfn.png). how does this work and if it's really running in dual channel would it still work if i changed the 2gb one with a new 8gb stick?

Comment: IIRC dual channel with different capacity sticks is possible, but rare. Either that's the case here, or the indication of dual channel being enabled is incorrect.

Comment: Intel machines can operate in "flex" mode where they use dual channel for the size of the smallest module, and single channel for the rest. See the duplicate and [Intel: Single- and Multichannel Memory Modes](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005657/boards-and-kits.html) (Flex is at the bottom of the page)

Comment: I was going to buy another 4gb stick to replace the 2gb one because anything above would result in single channel. does flex mode mean if i get a 8gb stick instead, the first 8gb of ram will be the same performance as dual channel and the rest will be single channel, making it better than a 4gb stick even if i don't use more than 8gb of ram?

Comment: If you get an 8GB stick then the first 4GB of each (total 8) will be dual channel, because you have a 4GB stick "built in". It should be somewhat better than what you currently have at least, and if you need more memory but don't mind slightly slower then it's fine. For most things you probably won't notice the difference.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answers.